# Crystal Reports in VB.net with datatable

Tags: crystal-reports

!!

I'm using crystal report in my project of vb.net. I'm using visual studio 2010,sql server2008 and SAP crystal report.there is an error that i can not overcome/solve.here is my code:

```
  Dim database As New Database
  Dim dr As DataRow
  Dim dt As Data.DataTable
  Dim report As New CrystalReportChalan
  Dim query1 As String
  Try
        query1 = "select per_name,f_name,per_address,rem_amount from person_info  "
        database.creatConn()
        dt = database.getDS(query1, "person_info")
        'dr = dt.Rows(0)
        MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count)  // Here the no of rows displayed


        report.SetDataSource(dt)   //Error 'Report has no table'

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

- there is a separated class for Database connection
- that class has function to get data from database.

Comment: Instead of using datatable as datasource, can you try with a dataset. You can refer the samples from here [http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t44560-crystal-reports-setdatasource-method.aspx](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t44560-crystal-reports-setdatasource-method.aspx) [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/1838f8a3-0b35-4b0d-b4a3-9556d28e320d](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/1838f8a3-0b35-4b0d-b4a3-9556d28e320d)

Comment: What is the exception/error message that is thrown?

Comment: yes dear, i also tried dataset, but received the same error.What do say about 'report.setDataSource(dt)', is this a right way ?? Suggest me some other some other method,if u can.thnx